# Generate closing divs in WP loop with php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to php and Wordpress and what I am trying to accomplish is listing all my posts by month+year. The month+year is shown as a link, which when clicked, toggles the days. My css code looks like this and is working properly (toggle function done by jquery).

```
<div class="monat"> <!-- month div -->
    <a href="#" title="Oktober 2014" class="zeigeTage">Oktober 2014</a> <!-- Toggle Button -->
         <div class="tage"> <!-- toggle div - shown when toggle button clicked -->
            <a href="#" title="#" class="tag">12</a> <!-- day of month -->
            <a href="#" title="#" class="tag">20</a> <!-- day of month -->
            <a href="#" title="#" class="tag">22</a> <!-- day of month -->
            <a href="#" title="#" class="tag">23</a> <!-- day of month -->
    </div>    <!-- end toggle div -->     
</div>  <!-- end month div -->
```

That´s what I have accomplished so far in php. The problem is, that i need 2 closing divs at the end (for class monat and class tage) and I am not sure how to implement them in the php code...

```
<?php

$prev_month = '';
$prev_year = '';

while(have_posts())

{
  the_post();
  if(get_the_time('F') != $prev_month || get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year)

  {
  echo '<div class="monat"><a href="#" title="#" class="zeigeTage">'.get_the_time('F Y').'</a><div class="tage">';
  }

?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="#" class="tag"><?php the_time('j'); ?></a>

<?php
   $prev_month = get_the_time('F');
   $prev_year = get_the_time('Y');
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help,
Andreas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've already found out how to detect the month change event:

```
$month_changed = (get_the_time('F') != $prev_month) 
                 || (get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year);
if ($month_changed) {
    ...
}
```

and you output (here I've placed ...) the opening of the divs already. But you're still missing when to place the close of those.

First of all you only need to place closing div tags when you have opened any. You can do this very similar like you do with the months check, just with another variable:

```
$prev_month = '';
$prev_year = '';
$divs_opened = false; ## third variable

while (have_posts()) {
    ...
```

So now when you for the first time open the divs, set that `$divs_opened` variable to `true`:

```
$month_changed = (get_the_time('F') != $prev_month) 
                 || (get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year);
if ($month_changed) {
    $divs_opened = true;
    ...
}
```

And as you need to close the divs if they were already opened, you need to check for that, too:

```
$month_changed = (get_the_time('F') != $prev_month) 
                 || (get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year);
if ($month_changed) {
    if ($divs_opened) {
        echo "</div></div>";
    }
    $divs_opened = true;
    ...
}
```

so now this is nearly done, but there is one more place you need to close the divs (if opened), too: that is after the loop:

```
$prev_month = '';
$prev_year = '';
$divs_opened = false; ## third variable

while (have_posts()) {
    ...
}

if ($divs_opened) {
    echo "</div></div>";
}
```

That should do it. And I hope it gives you the pointers that you can use a similar method how you detected the month change for the closing divs, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, hakre!
Works like a charm!

Here is the edited code:

```
<?php
                        $prev_month = '';
                        $prev_year = '';
                        $divs_opened = false;

                        query_posts( 'category_name=wurst' );

                        while(have_posts()) { ## Loop Start

                            the_post();
                            $month_changed = (get_the_time('F') != $prev_month) || (get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year);
                            if ($month_changed) {
                                if ($divs_opened) {
                                    echo "</div></div>";
                                }
                                $divs_opened = true;

                                {
                                echo '<div class="monat"><a href="#" title="#" class="zeigeTage">'.get_the_time('F Y').'</a><div class="tage">';
                                }
                            }
                    ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="tag"><?php the_time('j'); ?></a>
                    <?php
                            $prev_month = get_the_time('F');
                            $prev_year = get_the_time('Y');
                        } ## Loop End

                        if ($divs_opened) {
                            echo "</div></div>";
                        }
                    ?>
```